# Dockerized nginx hangs after thousands of requests

Tags: docker, nginx, reverse-proxy, freeze

I've met a weird issue when using the dockerized nginx.
Will get hanging requests after hundreds if I was using the JMeter to request the backend service through the reverse proxy of nginx.
I have tried with the postman while the requests hanged,  it's replayable (sometimes), but it is always OK if request the backend service directly.

I've tried without docker on the same configuration, no hanged requests.

Does anyone know how to resolve it?

Comment: Do the load-balancing process.

Comment: @ArunachalamE I think that only make the problem delays occur, but can't resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I know why that because of the connection numbers between the reverse proxy and backend service exceeded.

Refers to [keepalive](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#keepalive), I modified the Nginx configuration to use the keepalive directive to active the cache for connections, this resolved this problem.

```
http {
    ...
    upstream http_backend {
        server 192.168.2.100:8081;
        keepalive 32;
    }
    ...
    server {
        ...
        location /api/ {
            proxy_pass http://http_backend/;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Connection "";
            ...
        }
    }
}
```